# What is the difference between "paid", "bonus" and "free" premium currency?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world

In many free-to-play video games, when you purchase premium currency, there's always (in the backend) a distinction between "purchased" and "bonus" currency. I don't mean in the case of free/paid, for example:

- Valorant Points (paid) and Kingdom Credits (free) from Valorant,
- Cash/Keys (paid) and Coins (free) from Farmville
- Riot Points (paid) and Blue Essence/Influence Points (free) from League of Legends
- Gems (paid) and *literally anything else* (free) from any Supercell (or generally 90% of the time) game.

Is there any reason for this distinction? Some sort of law or regulation?
Also, functionally, are there any differences in this? (Do some games prevent some types of items based on whether they were free/bonus/paid?, especially maybe in Japan and Korea?)

I mean like this:

[image: Purchased/Bonus and Earned V-Bucks in Fortnite]

Note: You can "earn" V-Bucks in Fortnite: Save the World by being a grandfathered legacy player.

Comment: I wasn't sure what tag since this is an "in-general" question. Since I used fortnite as the guineapig, that's what I'm tagging with. Someone feel free to correct my tags.

Answer (score 1):

In my country (Japan), premium currency is commonly used in games such as [gacha games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gacha_game), and some of the gachas in the game offer paid premium currency only gacha (meaning "free" bonus premium currency cannot be used for that gacha). Those kinds of gacha guarantee 1 highest rarity character, card, etc.

Also, according to the [Japanese website](https://topcourt-law.com/finance/fund_settlement_app_charges#i-19), the distinction between paid and free/bonus currency is to make it clear whether it's actually paid or not. This makes refunding their money easier, if anything happened to the game(such as EOL).

I don't know about other country's law or regulation and such, but I'd imagine it should be similar to our law, because why not?

Comment: I can't access the website (I think it's geoblocked), but what about "regular" and "bonus" paid currency? Most gatchas iirc only use "Free" and "Paid"; no "bonus". Bonus is just rolled into paid.

Comment: @aytimothy For the game that I play (Arknights/Granblue), every bonus currency is rolled into "free" premium currency. I don't know about Fortnite, but if a bonus is rolled into paid, it sounds like it would make refunding more difficult. For example, if you buy 10000 currency and get 1000 bonus currency, you get 11000 currency. How do you determine if that 1000 currency - labeled as paid currency - was purchased by purchasing 1000 currency or not?

Comment: ... By the way, can you define what "regular" premium currency is? Is it like the one that you get by playing games?

Comment: "regular" = Purchased V-Bucks, "bonus" = Bonus V-Bucks (ie. for the highest tier, that is 10k "regular" plus 3.5k "bonus" for a total of 13.5k. For the lowest, that's just 1k "regular")